# Python won't return my search string when searching for items in a list

Tags: python-3.x, full-text-search

This shouldn't be too difficult just cant wrap my head around it...

Here is my main search function:

```
def search_configurations(input_dict={}, output_dict={}, search_strings=None, search_strings_dict = None, ):
#arguments are input_dict, typically configration files saved to a dict
#last 2 arguments are optional and will be searched against input_dict
search_strings = [word + "\n" for word in search_strings]
print(search_strings)

for key, value in input_dict.items():
    value = str(value)
    value = value.strip("{}")
    print("*" * 20)
    print("\n"* 5)
    config_blocks = value.split('\\n!')
    # print(config_blocks)
    # print(len(config_blocks))

    # Iterate through each block and check if all items in the search string list exist in the block
    for block in config_blocks:
        block_lines = block.split('\n')

        block_items = [line.strip() for line in block_lines]
        print(block_items)
        if all(search_item in block_items for search_item in search_strings):
            # If all search strings are found in this block, print or store the result
            print("Configuration found:")
            print(block)
            print("=" * 400)
```

Here in another file I'm attempting to run searches:

```
omega = ["router ospf 1", "network 10.0.1.0 0.0.0.127 area 1"]

search_configurations(input_dict = config_dict_before, search_strings= omega )
```

when I print(block_items)  i get this output:
['\ninterface FastEthernet4/0\n no ip address\n shutdown\n duplex full']
**['\nrouter ospf 1\n router-id 5.5.5.5\n redistribute bgp 650 subnets route-map BGP_TO_OSPF\n network 10.0.1.0 0.0.0.127 area 1\n network 10.0.2.0 0.0.0.127 area 1'] (truncated - each item surrounded by [] is a block)**

Obviously all my items in my omega list exist in block_items but nothing is being returned.

I even tried something like this: omega = ['\nrouter ospf 1\n router-id 5.5.5.5\n redistribute bgp 650 subnets route-map BGP_TO_OSPF\n network 10.0.1.0 0.0.0.127 area 1\n network 10.0.2.0 0.0.0.127 area 1']

Neither one of these search results is giving a match when
I run if all(search_item in block_items for search_item in search_strings)  :: search_strings = omega in this context.

Any advice?

Comment: Initializing a parameter with an empty list or dictionary is [probably not doing what you expect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1132941/least-astonishment-and-the-mutable-default-argument).

Comment: @JonSG I see what what you're saying. I was going to clear the dictionaries in between different updates and calls to the dictionary. My issue is it doesn't seem to be finding the search string in the dictionary per block, even when I print out each block and the string seems to exist.